# Can I hide the list of selected elements from the v-autocomplete input box?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify's `v-autocomplete` (v. 1.5) to create a dropdown as follows:

```html
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="autoCompleteSelected"
    placeholder="Select options from the list"
    :items="items"
    :item-text="'name'"
    :item-value="'id'"
    :search-input.sync="autoCompleteInput"
    return-object
    hide-selected
    multiple
/>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/chk1/pen/bGVPYKa

After a selection is made, the values of selected items end up in the input box, to the left of the *actual* input where a user can type into. The placeholder is also hidden. Can I suppress this behaviour?

My goal is to basically completely remove an item from the autocomplete's input and list after it has been selected (because I want to list the selected items somewhere else), but I would like to keep `v-autocomplete` (internal) variables to avoid redundant data handling. Using `hide-selected` only removes items from the selection dropdown.

[image: Screenshots from devtools]

In theory I could apply the CSS `.v-select__selection { display:none }`, however the input's placeholder is still missing if there are any items in the autocomplete's `v-model`.

Comment: Have you figured out the way to do that? I mean other than apply `display:none` to it

Answer (score 1):

yes you can with simple hack

```
  <v-autocomplete
    v-model="selectedValue"
    :items="list"
    item-value="display"
    item-text="name"
    outlined
    v-bind="attrs"
    v-on="listeners"
    return-object
    hide-selected
  >
    <template v-slot:selection="">
     
    </template>
  </v-autocomplete>
```

the key is use selection template slot without data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I know how you can show the placeholder just with overriding the style.
If you are using scoped style then you would need to specify `::v-deep`

```
.v-select__selection { display:none }
::v-deep .v-select.v-input--is-dirty ::placeholder {
  color: back !important; // it's set to `transparent` by vuetify
}
```